# TM that finds the middle of an input string in O(n) time

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Is it possible to find a TM with O(n) complexity that finds the middle of an input string?
Or at least to prove that it cannot be done?

I can use a two-taped TM if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a two tape TM it is not difficult:

Move to the right on the input tape. Every second step write something to the secondary tape. Once you reach a blank on the input tape (i.e. the end of the input), start moving to the left on the input tape. Each step delete a symbol from the secondary tape. You have reached the middle if the second tape is empty.

Comment: Yes, that'll do, tx. However, can we state that with a single tape it is not doable?

Comment: My intuition says its not possible in linear time without a second tape, but I'm bad at lower bound proofs.